# How to conditionally add rows to table in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am new to Angular 5. I have an array of objects in my `app.component.ts`. I want to use both `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` to create rows of a table and apply condition at the same time. Basically something like

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows" *ngIf="row['category']==='M'"><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

This is however not allowed and an error is displayd:

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **`ng-container`**([documentaion link](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue))  for your **`ngFor`**.

```
<ng-container *ngFor= "let row of rows">
   <tr  *ngIf="row['category']==='M'"><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
</ng-container>
```